# How to display RSS feed link on WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, rss

I have a WordPress site running WordPress 3.0.1, and I'd like to know how I can display an RSS link on my site so that my readers can subscribe to my update feed.

I'd like something like the one at the very bottom right corner of the Wordpress.org home page that says:

[image: Feed icon][Blog RSS](http://wordpress.org/news/feed/)

http://wordpress.org/

Is there a option I can enable to add this?

Comment: Have you tried http://wordpress.org/support/ ? This site is for end users using wordpress.com blogs. A start for you will to be look at your footer.php file (if you have one)

Comment: How am I not an end user?  I have a wordpress blog.  I'm trying to learn how to use it.  Is it because I'm using a wordpress.org blog instead of a wordpress.com blog?

Comment: yes that is the reason. As discussed in [meta.webapps](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-should-we-do-with-wordpress-questions-and-how-tag-them/203#203). Opening the site to wordpress.org means we open up for questions dealing with hosting companies, hosting packages to work with WP, themes, customizations, plugins, html CSS etc. I *heard* that webmasters.stackexchange.com is slowly accepting wordpress questions but I would word it in way that is acceptable there. Adding to my starting hint you can use the 'bloginfo' command - `<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>`

Comment: There is a Webmaster stackexchange site, ask again there.

Comment: I have reopened your question and bumped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be pretty straightforward with no programming necessary:

```
1.  Go to Site Admin.

2.  Select Appearance on the left.

3.  Select Widgets

4.  Drag the Meta Widget over to the Primary Widget Area on the right.
```

Although this didn't put it at the bottom of the page, it is an easy way to show a link to your site's RSS feed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you searched the WordPress Codex? Here is the link: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds